# Microsoft access Query rolling total every 5 lines not using dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, cumulative-sum

I am new to Microsoft access.

I need a query that will allow me to sum a rolling total for every 5 lines of data.  So on the sixth day I need a line to drop off the total and the new line to be added.

```
Fields:
ID, Daily_SUM
```

The results should be

```
ID  Daily sum   Weekly Sum
1   12  
2   41  
3   46  
4   125 
5   120 344
6   42  374
7   41  374
8   57  385
9   207 467
10  215 562
11  187 707
12  -43 623
13  45  611
14  56  460
15  40  285
16  8   106
17  95  244
18  580 779
19  360 1083
20  337 1380
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a correlated subquery.  The challenge is actually getting `NULL` values on the first few rows:

```
select t.id, t.daily,
       (select iif(count(*) = 7, sum(t3.daily), NULL)
        from (select top 7 t2.daily
              from table t2
              where t2.id <= t.id
              order by t2.id desc
             ) t3
       ) as weekly
from table t;
```

EDIT:

If we assume that the ids are assigned sequentially with no gaps, then you can use an explicit join:

```
select t.id, t.daily,
       iif(count(*) = 7, sum(t2.daily), NULL) as weekly
from table t inner join
     table t2
     on t2.id between t.id - 6 and t.id
group by t.id, t.daily;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.  But I am getting the following error.

Comment: The syntax of the subquery in this expression is incorrect.  Check the subquery's syntax and enclose the subquery in parentheses.

Comment: @user3142627 . . . The subquery *is* in parentheses.  Is that the rror you are getting?

Comment: Yes this is the error.  I've tried a few things.  Is there a way to send you this sample DB?

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I am getting the same error with the new explicit join.

Comment: one thing maybe is that the daily data is from a query and is not part of the table.

Comment: That would be the subquery that is causing the problem then.

Comment: to get the daily data I simply added two fields daily: ([D_NH_NYSE]-[D_NL_NYSE])